# Confusion on endianness with ARM processor

Tags: memory, arm, endianness

I'm quite puzzled about the endianness on an ARM device. The device I'm testing uses little endian.

Say there's code here which swaps elements in an array:

```
uint32_t* srcPtr = (uint32_t*)src->get();
uint8_t* dstPtr = dst->get();

dstPtr[0] = ((*srcPtr) >> 16) & 0xFF;
dstPtr[1] = ((*srcPtr) >> 8) & 0xFF;
dstPtr[2] = (*srcPtr) & 0xFF;
dstPtr[3] = ((*srcPtr) >> 24);
```

My understanding is that if srcPtr contains {0, 1, 2, 3} the output dstPtr should be {1, 2, 3, 0}.

But the output is dstPtr is {2, 1, 0, 3}.

Does this mean that the srcPtr read in this way 3, 2, 1 -> 0 ?

Can someone please help me ? :)

Is this due to the little endian ?

Answer (score 1):

so at address 0x100 I have the values 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33.  0x00 is at 0x100, 0x11 at 0x101 and so on.  If I point at address 0x100 with a 32 bit unsigned pointer, then I get the value 0x33221100, true for ARM (little endian), true for x86 (little endian) etc.

So now if I take 0x33221100 and (x>>16)&0xFF I get 0x22. (x>>8)&0xFF is 0x11, x&0xFF is 0x00 and (x>>24)&0xFF is 0x33.    {2,1,0,3}

Where is your confusion?  Is it the conversion from 0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33 to 0x33221100?  Little endian, least significant byte first, so the lowest or first address you come across (0x100) has the least significant byte (0x00 the lower 8 bits of the number) and so on 0x101 the next least significant bits 8 to 15, 0x102 bits 16 to 23 and 0x103 bits 24 to 31.  for a 32 bit value.

Comment: Now big endian on an arm processor, that is confusing, esp when some are BE32 and some are BE8....